# Changing "likes" based on what picture is shown

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am making an app based off Nasa's api that shows a picture or video each day. I have also created a like button that toggles if a person clicks it to like a picture or to toggle it back to default. I created the app in a way where a user can select a date using a calendar component that is through material-ui and when they select a date, it will bring the picture or video from that date. I am trying to figure out how to attach the like button to each picture, so that if they like one picture, they can go to another day and it will let them like another picture. Currently, for example, if I like today's picture, select the calendar and go to yesterday's picture, my like button is still toggled. Here is the code I used for getting the pictures and other information to show:

```js
export default function PictureOfDay(props) {
    const [picture, setPicture] = useState([])
    const {date} = props;
    let selectDate = moment(date, "ddd MMM DD YYYY HH:mm:ss Z-HHmm");
    let formatDate = selectDate.format("YYYY-MM-DD");

    useEffect(() => {
        axios.get(
          `https://api.nasa.gov/planetary/apod?api_key=QQpTYaQHDUvPAyVorMgxfKhQEoSQikBYt5WuFCf6&date=${formatDate}`
        )
        .then((response) => {
            console.log(response.data);
            setPicture(response.data);
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log(err)
        });
    }, [formatDate]);


    return (
      <div className="info">
        {props.fetchingData && (
          <div className="key spinner">
            <Loader type="Puff" color="#800080" height="60" width="60" />
            <p>Loading Data</p>
          </div>
        )}
        <PictureInfo
          date={picture.date}
          title={picture.title}
          image={picture.url}
          media={picture.media_type}
          explanation={picture.explanation}
        />
      </div>
    );
}
```

I also have my Like button logic on a different component. Right now, it is not attached to the pictures and I am unsure how to go about doing that:

```js
import React, {useState, useEffect} from "react";
import ToggleHearts from "./ToggleHearts"
import {
    Button,
    Typography,
} from "@mui/material";
import {makeStyles} from "@mui/styles";

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  button: {
    ...theme.typography.buttons,
    fontFamily: "Orbitron",
    padding: "0.7em",
    fontSize: "1.5em",
    width: "3.2em",
    height: "3.2em",
    background: theme.palette.primary.mainGradient,
    border: "2px solid pink",
    "&:hover": {
      background: theme.palette.secondary.mainGradient,
    },
  },
}));


const Likes = () => {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const [liked, setLiked] = useState(false)
    const handleChangeHeart = () => {
        setLiked((previousHeart) => {
            return !previousHeart;
        });
    };
   
    useEffect(() => {
        setLiked(JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("liked")));
    }, [])

    useEffect(() => {
        window.localStorage.setItem('liked', liked);
    }, [liked])

    return (
      <Button
        className={classes.button}
        variant="contained"
        onClick={handleChangeHeart}
      >
        <Typography style={{ fontFamily: "Orbitron" }}>
          <ToggleHearts liked={liked}/>
        </Typography>
      </Button>
    );
}

export default Likes
```

The Likes component is just attached to my component that renders everything on the page, here is the code to that:

```js
export default function PictureInfo(props) {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
    const handleOpen = () => setOpen(true);
    const handleClose = () => setOpen(false);
    const newDate = moment(props.date).format("dddd, MMMM, Do YYYY");
  
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <Grid
          container
          direction="row"
          justifyContent="center"
          alignItems="center"
        >
          <Grid item className={classes.formGridItem}>
            <Typography variant="h2">Date: {newDate}</Typography>
          </Grid>
          <Grid item className={classes.formGridItem}>
            <Typography variant="h2">Title of Photo: {props.title}</Typography>
          </Grid>
        </Grid>
        <Grid
          container
          direction="column"
          justifyContent="center"
          alignItems="center"
        >
          <Grid item className={classes.formGridItem}>
            {props.media === "video" ? (
              <iframe
                className={classes.image}
                title="video"
                src={props.image}
                width="800px"
                height="600px"
              ></iframe>
            ) : (
              <img className={classes.image} alt="nasa" src={props.image} />
            )}
          </Grid>
          <Likes />
          <Grid item className={classes.formGridItem} align="center">
            <Button
              className={classes.button}
              variant="contained"
              onClick={handleOpen}
            >
              Click here for more information!
            </Button>
          </Grid>
          <Modal
            open={open}
            onClose={handleClose}
            aria-labelledby="modal-modal-title"
            aria-describedby="modal-modal-description"
          >
            <Box sx={style}>
              <Typography
                id="modal-modal-title"
                style={{
                  borderBottom: "1px solid pink",
                  fontFamily: "'Orbitron', sans-serif",
                  marginBottom: "1em",
                  fontSize: "1.4em",
                }}
              >
                Explanation of: {props.title}
              </Typography>
              <Box
                style={{
                  background: "white",
                  border: "1px solid purple",
                  padding: "2em",
                }}
              >
                <Typography
                  id="modal-modal-description"
                  variant="subtitle2"
                  style={{ fontSize: "1.2em" }}
                >
                  {props.explanation}
                </Typography>
              </Box>
            </Box>
          </Modal>
          <footer>
            <Typography
              variant="subtitle2"
              style={{ fontSize: "1rem", color: "black" }}
            >
              &copy;2021 Charlene Johnson
            </Typography>
          </footer>
        </Grid>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If i right to understand you
all picture or video posts, must have an unique ID in you data represent, you data for this must look like this for example:

[{
id:'id of post',
likes:[idOfUsers],
...other needed for you data
}]

So, now you can check for likes id of user, and toggle you 'like button', if ID of user exist in this post into a  'likes'  array,
or store IDs of posts to 'postsWhichwasLiked':[idsOfPosts],
and then to define which of posts was  liked across getting id from this array and then to  comparing with ID of post